# Bind data to grid view from different sources

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding

I have gridview in my asp.net page, the get the data after page_load from the database directly.

```
        string sqlSelect = "SELECT *  FROM users";
        SqlCommand obj_Cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, con2);

        SqlDataReader obj_Reader = obj_Cmd.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        while (obj_Reader.Read())
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Id"] = obj_Reader["Id"];
            row["Name"] = obj_Reader["Name"];
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

and thats work fine, the gridview load the data,
in the same page i have another datasource that should displayed in the gridview. the user can enter another name and it must be shown in the gridview with out deleting what exist.

```
        GridView1.DataSource = tableInsertedFromUsers;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

what happend, when the user inserting another name (access the second datasource) every thing in the gridview deleted, and just displayed the second datasource and not the first.

i want to show both of them in the gridview.

any idea ? please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable `var` first and store `GridView1.DataSource`. Then declare a second variable `var` to store the second datasource. Add them together into one datasource and bind the grid with this final datasource. 
And how to save result of a query in a variable, read this [How to get SQL result saved into a C# variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045097/how-to-get-sql-result-saved-into-a-c-sharp-variable)

Comment: Hi Rehan,
this will not work, because you can't add them together.

Comment: @user2274204 Read <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974381/how-to-combine-two-data-source-into-one> Hope it helps.